# I have a static list of items with a title and a description that I want to use in multiple separate components, do I need to use state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

It is a list of steps in a process that looks like this

```
[
  { title: 'Upload file', description: 'Here you can upload your file and ....'},
  { title: 'Pick a color', description: 'You can choose any primary color or ...'}
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

Now I have multiple components that use this list, I see multiple ways to use it in these components:

A) I'll just make a object out of this and store it in a file and then pass it as a argument at my top level component. However, the components that use this are nested at different levels.

B) I'll make a object out of this and store it in a file and export it. Then I'll import this in every component that uses it.

C) Store it in a context and use the context. However, I wonder what the benefit of that is over A and B?

Am I missing any options? Do you recommend one of these approaches over the other and if so why? If you have any reading material regarding this subject, I would love to learn soe

Comment: Your question is vague iow not easy to answer as the question is not clearly understood. In case you are referring to a javascript object from your json. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184547/create-an-array-of-objects-from-json

Answer (score 1):

There is not much information about the rest of your code, but in general I would go for option B. There is no need for state or context if the list never changes. You might even think about putting it in a `.json` file if you don't need types as it is more configuration than code.

If you would need change detection on the list you could go for:

- State if it is only used in one component
- Context if it is shared between multiple components

Answer (score 1):

Don't do A), it'll lead to prop drilling where you're forced to pass otherwise contextual data through components that have nothing to do with it.

B) is just fine if this list is static, and doesn't change dynamically.

C) is ok, if the data does need to change, but you can introduce that after first doing B, when you actually need that ability. I would however advise you to use context only for dep injection (injecting "services" into components whose references don't- or rarely change) and to use a something better for sharing state in a performant and concurrency-safe way, like [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand).